# SQL - EXISTS and NOT EXISTS with inequality

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, exists

[image: Considerf having the following tabes]

Consider having these two tables and the following queries:

```
SELECT Product. *
FROM Product
WHERE EXISTS 
       ( SELECT *
         FROM Codes
         WHERE  Product.P_code <> Codes.P_code)
```

And

```
SELECT Product. *
FROM Product
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
       ( SELECT *
         FROM Codes
         WHERE  Product.P_code <> Codes.P_code)
```

Is the following reasoning correct?

1.The first query will produce two entries because there are two P_code rows in Codes that are not identical to the ones in Product.
 2. The subquery will return two entries, but they will be eliminated by the NOT condition in the main query, which will return zero rows.

I am not sure how the reasoning  in these queries works. I can easily predict when the query will print out 2 or 3 rows, but I do not know how it works in cases in which it may print 0 or 5 rows (depending on the EXISTS/NOT EXISTS condition and the equality/inequality sign).

Can somebody elaborate on this or send me a good reading? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasoning is not correct.  But, this is easy enough to verify, so you should run the queries yourself.

The first query will return all rows in `Product`.  Why?  Because for each code there is at least one row in `Codes` where the inequality is true.  For instance, code `'P_01'` does not match `'P_03'`, so there exists a code that does not match.

The second query will return no rows in `Product`.  Why?  Because there is a non-matching code for every product code.  Because such a code exists, the `not exists` fails.

I would suggest that you stick with equality conditions in your `exists` and `not exists` statements.  The logic is easier to follow and less prone to error.

Comment: Thank you! I  needed to know the reasoning behind those queries because of my final exam, I will most likely never use such format (with inequality signs) in practice.

Answer (score 1):

EXISTS return TRUE if inner query returns at least one record.

So in first query, EXISTS returns TRUE for all products because there are at least one record in CODES which is not matching the product code in PRODUCT.

A simple visualization given below.

[image]

In contrast, NO EXISTS return TRUE if no rows returned from inner query. Inn above example there are no such situations and returns nothing.

Reference from [oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)

Comment: Have a re-read of the sql - the queries include an inequality, not an equality. `Product.P_code <> Codes.P_code`